# HTML table scraping - table object returned as 1 big cell instead of separate elements

Tags: excel, vba, web-scraping

I've been working on a webpage scraping program from within excel VBA (with lots of help from this forum).

I've gotten stuck at a table which shows a single row, which I need to automate clicking.  I used the same method for a similar table earlier in the process and that worked fine:

```
   setting the HTML table to IEtable object

   using ietable.rows(1).click
```

This table however, returns as 1 cell containing the values of all the separate elements I see on the webpage and the .click function doesn't work.

This is the HTML code for the table I am trying to access:

```html
<table id="tblPatientList" class="tblTabBody" style="height: 143px; width: 653px;" cellspacing="2" cellpadding="0">
    <tbody>
        <tr style="height: 100%; width: 100%;">
            <td style="width: 649px; height: 100%;">
                <div id="divPatientList" style="overflow: auto; width: 100%; height: 100%; background-color: white;">
                    <table id="dgrPatients" class="tblpat" style="border-width: 0px; width: 100%; border-collapse: collapse;" border="0" rules="all" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="1">
                        <tbody>
                            <tr class="headerBlue">
                                <td style="width: 5%;">&nbsp;</td>
                                <td style="width: 15%;">Hosp No.</td>
                                <td style="width: 15%;">Surname</td>
                                <td style="width: 15%;">Forename</td>
                                <td style="width: 10%;">DOB</td>
                                <td style="width: 2%;">Sex</td>
                                <td style="width: 10%;">NHS Number</td>
                                <td style="width: 25%;">Address</td>
                                <td class="screenOnlyOutput" style="width: 5%;" align="center">List</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr class="even" style="color: red;">
                                <td align="center">&nbsp;</td>
                                <td><strong>12345678</strong></td>
                                <td>ANONYMOUS FIRST NAME</td>
                                <td>ANONYMOUS LAST NAME</td>
                                <td>dd/mm/yyyy</td>
                                <td align="center">M</td>
                                <td>123&nbsp;456&nbsp;7890&nbsp;<img style="cursor: hand; vertical-align: middle; border: 0px;" title="Number present and verified" src="/icedesktop/dotnet/icedesktop/images/tick.gif" /></td>
                                <td>ANONYMOUS ADDRESS</td>
                                <td class="screenOnlyOutput" align="center"><input id="dgrPatients_ctl02_chkAddOrRemove" style="border: 0px; height: 12px;" name="dgrPatients$ctl02$chkAddOrRemove" type="checkbox" /></td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

This table always only returns 2 rows - a header and 1 data row.  I try to click it with:

```
Set ieTbl = ieDoc.Document.frames(0).Document.all.tblPatientList
    If Not ieTbl Is Nothing Then
    ieTbl.Rows(1).Click
    Set ieTbl = Nothing
End If
```

When I examine the ietable object in the immediate window, it only has 1 row and 1 column, containing all the separate cells on the html page in 1 cell in the ietbl object.

Why is it doing this?

Comment: Can you share the site link?

Comment: The table your selecting has one row, `grPatients` has two and a click event

Comment: ieDoc.getElementById("dgrPatients_ctl02_chkAddOrRemove").click ?

Comment: Thanks NickSlash - I missed the table within a table